# 'sudo apt-get install' is showing "Not using locking for read only file /var/lib/dpkg/lock" warning on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, read-only, lock

I just installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7.

Unfortunately I can't install anything from the terminal app:

If I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install yasm -y git make g++ build-essential libminiupnpc-dev
```

I get:

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I've rebooted the device but wasn't successful yet. What should I do to fix the error?

Comment: Can you add `lsblk` to your question? Also, you can try `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: Clipper, it would be great if you could add the solution as an answer and accept it to move this out of unanswered.

Comment: @JulianStirling Unfortunately I can't answer to my own questions.

"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 1/4/2014 5:29:31 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Also I don't now how to move it out of unanswered. Can you help me?

The solution was sudo mount -o remount,rw /

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> **Warning:** This is *by design*. What you're trying to do can very quickly make your device unusable. Phones, which are updated by `apt-get upgrade` for example, are not tested; only the ones using the OTA update system are. If your phone breaks, you may need to re-flash it. If you understand the risk, then see below.

To remount the root filesystem as read/write, run the following command

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: This also solved the same problem I was having on my Nexus 5, running Ubuntu Touch (installed by MultiROM).  I enabled Developer Mode, then ran this command, and all is well!  Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you do this, you can very quickly make your device unusable. We don't test phones which are updated by "apt-get upgrade" for example, only using the OTA update system. If your phone breaks, you may need to re-flash it.